# how to use :deep(.className) in vue 2

Tags: sass, vuejs2, vuejs3

i have working scss styles

```
.alert {
  ::v-deep .v-alert__border {
    top: 8px;
    bottom: 8px;
    border-radius: 200px;
  }
  &:not(&--rtl) {
    // styles
  }
}
```

I want to redo these styles like this.

```
 .alert {
    :deep(.v-alert__border) {
      top: 8px;
      bottom: 8px;
      border-radius: 200px;
    }
    &:not(&--rtl) {
      // styles
    } 
  }
```

The problem is that it doesn't work.
I use

```
"vue": "^2.6.11",
```

Found information that this functionality is not supported in `"vue": "^2.6.11"`,.

Is it really not supported or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I could not understand your question. If ```::v-deep``` works fine for your project, why you insist to use ```:deep(...)``` ?

Comment: i have warning messages about  ::v-deep is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the discussion found here: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4745

Every example starts with `:deep` and never nested?

```scss
  :deep(.alert.v-alert__border) {
    top: 8px;
    bottom: 8px;
    border-radius: 200px;
  }
```

---

```scss
  :deep(.alert) {
    .v-alert__border {
      top: 8px;
      bottom: 8px;
      border-radius: 200px;
    }
  }
```

Perhaps one of those two works?

Comment: in your link "vue": "^3.2.19" but i use "vue": "^2.6.11"

Comment: It can still be relevant if vue 2 vs vue 3 still use the same SASS compilers of similar versions, its more to do with the `vue-loaders` than explicitly the Vue version.

Another thread on Vue 2, suggets `>>>` instead of `deep`, depends on loader versions.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/913

Answer (score 0):

I tested these codes and they works for me. I am using vue version `2.6.11` and vue cli version `4.5` and sass version `1.26.5`:

> parent component:

```html
<template>
<section>
  <div class="myParent">
    <ChildAlert></ChildAlert>
  </div>

  <ChildAlert></ChildAlert>
</section>
</template>

<script>
import ChildAlert from "./ChildAlert";
export default {
  name: "AlertCompo",
  components: {
    ChildAlert
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

.myParent {
  background-color: #000;
  :deep(.myTitle) {
    color: red;
  }
}

</style>
```

> child component:

```html
<template>
<section>
  <h1 class="myTitle">this is Child component</h1>
</section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ChildAlert"
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```